What is undefined behaviour in these pointer conversions?
EDIT: Wow, this is a lot of information to the point, answers the "why" part, and solved my immediate problem. Still struggling with the "how" part, however. Your answers spark additional explanation, and bonus questions at the bottom.

I am designing a very minimal offset pointer class.
Its ultimate purpose are linked data structures in shared memory, which need to cope with varying virtual address offset in different processes. The idea is inspired by boost::interprocess::offset_ptr
My first test showed optimization level dependent output, suggesting undefined behaviour. How could it be fixed? See for example
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class NullableOffsetPtr
{
public:
    NullableOffsetPtr(T const* ptr) :
        offset_{
            ptr == nullptr ? std::ptrdiff_t{1} : reinterpret_cast<std::byte const*>(ptr) - reinterpret_cast<std::byte const*>(this)}
    {
    }

    T* get()
    {
        return offset_ == 1 ? nullptr : reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(this) + offset_);
    }

private:
    std::ptrdiff_t offset_; // Using units of bytes, as alignments of *this and *ptr may not match.
};

class Sample
{
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Sample sample;
    NullableOffsetPtr<Sample> ptr{&sample};

    std::cout << "(ptr.get() == &sample): " << (ptr.get() == &sample) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ptr.get(): " << ptr.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&sample  : " << &sample << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

With all optimization levels -O1 and above, the output of gcc compiled executables is
(ptr.get() == &sample): 0
ptr.get(): 0x7ffe503cd42f
&sample  : 0x7ffe503cd42f

with the pointer comparison evaluating to false, despite individual values (varying with each run) are shown to be the same!
Of course, reinterpret_cast immediately is ringing the UB bell, but from my understanding should be within the limits of Type aliasing in reinterpret_cast.
See also godbolt example
Bonus question 1: I understand the reasoning behind expr.add#4.2, restricting + and - to pointers targeting elements of the same array, which was explained in several comments. However, the very same could be accomplished by both pointer and pointer plus offset targets being within the same (nested) composition, not necessarily an array. Otherwise the offsetof macro would be pointless. Example:
#include <iostream>

struct Inner
{
    int i1;
    int i2;
};

struct Outer
{
    int i1;
    int i2;
    Inner inner;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Outer outer;
    std::cout << "&outer.i2 - &outer.i1: " << &outer.i2 - &outer.i1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "&outer.inner.i2 - &outer.i1: " << &outer.inner.i2 - &outer.i1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

returns
&outer.i2 - &outer.i1: 1
&outer.inner.i2 - &outer.i1: 3

All invold pointer targets are within the object outer, but no array is involved.
expr.add#4.2 talks about "(possibly-hypothetical) array element". Would that be met within the mentioned composition, or what else does "possibly-hypothetical" mean?
Bonus question 2: To which extent can boost::interprocess::offset_ptr prevent UB? Found the term "illegal but correct" in the context of inlining. However I'm neither understanding how inlining relates, nor whether there is a widely accepted illegal correctness, that could be verified. Any suggestions?

reinterpret cast from memory to a type is only allowed if that type is trivially constructible and trivially copyable (e.g. it must be a POD type). So you constrain T to satisfy those requirements.

@PepijnKramer Do you have a source for that? Note that OP's code doesn't rely on implicitly starting object's lifetime.

Also this code starts working if you put both variables as non-static members into the same class.

@HolyBlackCat I agree that remark could have been better (me bad)... but still this code does assume the lifetime of T has started.

@PepijnKramer Yep, and its lifetime did start, so if this is UB, it's for some other reason.

Just wondering, why the special handling of nullptr? Is there some obscure rule that would make that UB? Also, it made me wonder whether an offset 1 couldn't occur naturally without feeding in nullptr.

Addition and subtraction of two unrelated pointers is UB, i.e. ptr-this

What is the rationale of making subtraction of two pointers not related to the same array undefined behavior? and Why pointer subtraction is undefined behavior in C++? and What is the rationale for limitations on pointer arithmetic or comparison?

I don't like those dupes too much. You can cast to uintptr_t to make offset calculation well-defined, but it doesn't help make the subsequent *this ... + offset legal.

Please ask one and only question per question; don't ask "bonus" questions; if you have follow-up questions, ask a new question.

Sample is an empty class and since this has no observable effect in your code, it can share an address with NullableOffsetPtr.
As a result, &sample and ptr.get() could give you the same output when printed.
However, the pointer subtraction in the constructor of NullableOffsetPtr is undefined behavior:

When two pointer expressions P and Q are subtracted, the type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as std​::​ptrdiff_t in the  header ([support.types.layout]).

If P and Q both evaluate to null pointer values, the result is 0.
Otherwise, if P and Q point to, respectively, array elements i and j of the same array object x, the expression P - Q has the value i−j.
Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.



[expr.add] p5


You can only use pointer arithmetic to reach one object from another if both objects are subobjects (perhaps indirectly) of the same top-level object. (E.g. GCC starts behaving if you make both objects non-static data members of the same class instance.)
Here's the related wording:

[expr.add]/4.2 that says + can only be used to move a pointer between elements of the same array. Similarly, - can only subtract pointers between elements of the same array.
[basic.types.general]/4 that says you can treat objects as arrays of unsigned char.
[basic.lval]/11.3 blesses char, unsigned char, and std::byte, allowing access to any object through pointers/references to those, disregarding strict aliasing.

It's also commonly understood that you can't do pointer arithmetic in uintptr_t to work around [expr.add]/4.2, but I can't find the related wording right now. (I mean you can't jump between unrelated objects this way. You can use it to make - give you the right offset.)
From GCC manual:

When casting from pointer to integer and back again, the resulting pointer must reference the same object as the original pointer, otherwise the behavior is undefined. That is, one may not use integer arithmetic to avoid the undefined behavior of pointer arithmetic...

Wording on lifetimes and aliasing is a mess overall, and if you dig too deep, a lot of things turn out to be technically UB (or implied to be so), while not being enforced in practice. For example, there's a concept of a byte being reachable through a pointer. It's used in the description of std::launder, and as far as I can tell, nowhere else (the standard doesn't actually say anywhere that accessing an "unreachable" byte is UB).

I think you could use std::intptr_t to work around it, but you'd run into implementation-defined and honestly under-specified/under-documented effects with that instantly.

@JanSchultke Yeah, just edited that in. My understanding is that casting to [u]intptr_t lets you compute the offset safely (in practice at least), but it's not enough to bless the + to jump between unrelated objects.

IIUC, the only valid operation on a std::intptr_t is casting it back to the original pointer type. This isn't specified explicitly for std::intptr_t, but in the semantics of reinterpret_cast, which define the results of converting a pointer to an integer type. (This is from memory -- I've not reverified with the latest version of the standard.)

@JamesKanze Doing arithmetic on it is implementation-defined, I believe? I trust the implementation to return a correct integer from -, but not trust it to return a correct pointer from + (I also added a section from GCC manual on this).

@HolyBlackCat std::intptr_t is an integer type, and you can do anything you want with it that you can do with any integer. Once you've modified it's value, however, casting it back to a pointer type is undefined behavior.

HolyBlackCat, JanSchultke, @JamesKanze: Using an integral type does actually solve the UB problem! The code of NullableOffsetPtr doesn't really navigate between objects, but reproduces the original pointer used for construction on return of get(). It only requires that intptr_t(ptr) - intptr_t(this) + intptr_t(this) == intptr_t(ptr). Which is guaranteed for integral arithmetics. The argument would break as soon as my class attempts more, such as increment/decrement via offset calculation, but that's not intended. Thanks so much for your hints and help!

Correction: reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(ptr) - reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(this) + reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(this) == reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(ptr)
